# Getting started with Constraint Programming

Tags: constraint-programming

Looking for tips, tutorials, books and other resources to get started with Constraint Programming.

Comment: [OptaPlanner documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/) contains an explanation on Local Search algorithms such as Tabu Search, Simulated Annealing and Late Acceptance, as well as other algorithms such as Branch and Bound. It also explains how to think about scoring (hard vs soft, weighting, positive vs negative, pareto, etc)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a lot of excellent material available on the web once you get in the groove, but the links below are (IMO) good starting points (the ones I used).

[Programming with Constraints: An Introduction - (Course website)](https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/pstuckey/book/course.html)
[Programming with Constraints: An Introduction - (Google book)](http://books.google.ca/books?id=jBYAleHTldsC&dq=Programming+with+Constraints&pg=PP1&ots=QfhyTiUzBP&source=bn&sig=BuqKI2n2fkcPzek-8C-T9m82e0Q&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=4&ct=result#PPT437,M1)
[Online Guide to Constraint Programming](http://ktiml.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/constraints/)

Comment: Added a link I found. Hope it's OK. Better to have a complete correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

Constraint Handling Rules (CHR) is a language to develop own (problem specific) constraint solvers. Check this:

- [CHR Homepage](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/CHR/)

There you find links to

- ***WebCHR Online Demo*** (originally developed at LMU Munich, now beautified at Uni Ulm)
- Several implementations for **Prolog** (naturally) and **Haskell**, as well as a (unfortunately unmaintained) prototype for Java (JCK).

There is also a JavaScript implementation of CHR: http://chrjs.net (https://github.com/fnogatz/CHR.js)

Comment: https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/CHR/

Comment: Link updated, thanks!

Comment: There is also [a CHR implementation for JavaScript](http://chrjs.net/).

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can have a look at an introductory [course](http://www.ps.uni-sb.de/courses/cp-ss07/services.html) thought at the Saarland University about constraint programming. They do not use mozart as [dr_pepper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321535/getting-started-with-constraint-programming#321579) said but [Gecode](http://www.gecode.org/). Gecode is a follow-up language of mozart, implemented partly by the same people.

Comment: Gecode is actually not a language but a C++ framework. However, Gecode supports also MiniZinc, which is a modeling language.

Comment: The previous course is complete and with nice slides. For an faster result, overview: look at prolog ( the defacto language) tuts: http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/index.html#menu

Answer (score 4):

I recommend getting started with [mozart](http://www.mozart-oz.org/).  It is an open-source constraint programming language and the site has plenty of documentation that will get you started.

Comment: This link seems to be broken now. Will it be updated soon?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another link to a course website on [Constraint Programming](http://www.ict.kth.se/courses/ID2204/).

Earlier the course used Mozart/Oz for the assingments but it has now been replaced by [Gecode](http://gecode.org).

Comment: Your first link is dead.

Comment: Update for the first link: https://www.kth.se/social/course/ID2204/

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you look further in the following website on constraint programming maintaned by Håkan Kjellerstrand (a.k.a Hakank) at [Hakank's Homepage](http://www.hakank.org/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The question is asking for references. My reference answer is a link. Just look at all other answers. They are similar to mine because the question is asking for answers like this one.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft's Solver Foundation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/solverfoundation) has some easy-to-understand examples.

Answer (score 0):

The [handbook of constraint programming](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=Kjap9ZWcKOoC) is well thought of.

In trivia, [my supervisor from fourth year](http://portal.acm.org/author_page.cfm?id=81100589552)  university (which was a while ago now) is referenced there. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're a Java programmer, I recommend using [Cream: Class Library for Constraint Programming](http://bach.istc.kobe-u.ac.jp/cream/)